# Add force towards a point in Unity3d?

Tags: 2d, physics, unity

I have a Vector2 and want to move an object towards it...
(this vector2 is the mouse position when clicked and I made sure I get only one position when its clicked)

My initial thought was to apply

> Rigidbody2D.Addforce(my vector2)

but it acting strangely...
How can I push anything towards a point?

N.B: I wanna use physics for it.... because I want to get the pushing feel!

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind :p
I found it!

it works after this

> rigidbody.AddForce((whateverObject.transform.position -
>   transform.position).normalized * someFactor);